# Install Ubuntu Touch for tablet Nexus 7

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

After

```
phablet-flash -b
```

command and get `raring-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip` file 
at last appear this:

```
Validating download for raring-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip
Error while downloading, ensure connection
```

Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a *download error* issue.

A.  Try that step again.

**OR**

B.  Use the manual install method: [Manual Installation (near bottom of page)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install)

---

PS: I have successfully installed this (Nexus 7 Core) several times on different *Nexus 7* devices.